# C: Scanning While not EOF Loop Unexpected Results

Tags: c, scanf

I know there are many questions on the same topic of `scanf` until `EOF` is reached, but here's a particular case I haven't seen. Suppose I want to make a C program where the user enters a single character, and the program prints back the character and the number of times the user has entered a character until they press CTRL+D (EOF)

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char thing;
  int i=0;
  while(scanf("%c", &thing) != EOF){
    printf("time:%d, char:%c\n",i,thing);
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, the output is not as expected. It's the following:

```
f
time:0, char:f
time:1, char:

p
time:2, char:p
time:3, char:

m
time:4, char:m
time:5, char:
```

I'm not too sure why `i` is being incremented again, and why `printf` gets executed again. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: "user enters a single character," --> Did user also press the <Enter> key?  Try `printf("time:%d, char:%d\n",i,thing);` (c to d)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char thing;
  int i=0;
  while(scanf("%c", &thing) != EOF){
    if (thing!='\n') {
      printf("time:%d, char:%c\n",i,thing);
      i++;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth is the `if` inside the loop...? wouldn't putting the condition within the `while` conditional be more readable and concise? (i.e. `scanf("%c", &thing) != EOF && thing != '\n'`)...

Comment: @Myst I think the OP only wants to exit the while loop on a ctrl-D.

Comment: Good point... You're probably right, I'm a poor reader, I thought OP was attempting to read a line. Should have read more in depth :-p

Answer (score 0):

@user2965071

```
char ch;
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

With such a snippet one reads any ASCII character from the stream including new line, return, tab, or escape. Thus, inside the loop I would test the symbol read with one of the ctype-functions.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
  char thing;
  int i=0;
  while(1 == scanf("%c", &thing)){
    if (isalnum(thing)) {
        printf("time:%d, char:%c\n",i,thing);
        i++;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As for me, I think it's not a good idea to check scanf for returning EOF. I would rather check for the number of good read arguments.